# How do I change Gwibber themes or column settings?

Tags: 11.10, gwibber

After setting up my accounts with Gwibber, there is only one column showing all messages from each account. There are no controls or options to add columns, or to change what is seen in the single visible column (except to switch to replies or private messages). It is also impossible to change themes — the "Preferences" dialog has only "Options" and "Messages". This was all configurable in previous versions, so how do I configure Gwibber now?

This is on Ubuntu 11.10 with:

- unity 4.24.0-0ubuntu2.1
- libgtk-3-0 3.2.0-0ubuntu3
- gwibber 3.2.1-0ubuntu1.3

I am also using the Zukitwo Hybrid (blue) theme, installed manually and activated via the `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

This version of Gwibber was rewritten from the ground up, so while it has some slick features, it still misses some of its old features, which will probably return in the future if possible, but might not depending on the capabilities of the toolkit and the wishes/abilities of the developer(s).

Comment: Dang. It's a bit weird that Ubuntu didn't just stick with the older version then — surely being more capable should outweigh being GTK2 based. Oh well.

Comment: @detly: it wasn't just about capabilities. The new Gwibber is faster, more stable and easier for the developers to "hack on" going forward.